Trying to turn a numeric matrix into a scatterplot with geom_point
I am trying to plot a 5x6 numeric vector using ggplot and geom_point (after converting the vector to a dataframe), but I can't figure out the aes mappings to make the plot correctly. I think I am maybe not understanding how the rows and columns are connected to one in another in the matrix/dataframe.
I am trying to plot the results of the very simple function below:
I <- 5
J <- 6
N <- 2000
d <- 0.021
p <- (d + 1) / 2
X <- sapply(1:I, function(i){
  d + rnorm(J, 0, 2 * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N))
})
X

numeric matrix
I take these results and convert them to a dataframe:
X_df <- data.frame(X = X)

as dataframe
But from here, I am stuck. I don't know how to tell R to plot the columns as my x values and the rows as my y values. I am using ggplot and geom_point but I get various errors when I try different aes mappings for x and y so I am clearly missing something. I even tried to assign vectors as column and row names and then use those as my aes mappings and still no luck. I am sure this is very basic and simple but it is driving me crazy that I can't figure out how to do something so simple. The plot should look something like this:
plot
(Note: I'm about a month into to learning R through some online data science courses and I am really struggling with something that I feel should be so simple and basic. I looked through other posts here and can't quite find a solution that is working for me. I think there is something that I am not understanding and could really use some help!)

ggplot2 and other tidyverse packages often work most fluidly with "tidy," or "longer" data, where the series is specified in a column instead of arranged in separate columns. library(tidyverse); X_df |> pivot_longer(everything()) |> ggplot(aes(name, value)) + geom_point()

You need to "tidy" you data first.
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(X_df, everything(), names_to=c(".value", "group"), names_pattern="(.).(.)") |>
  ggplot(aes(x=group, y=X)) +
  geom_point()



Thanks for the replies. I am familiar with the tidyverse library, but not necessarily with the concept of "tidying" my data, so it looks like I have a new concept to learn!
